# Match everything but some specific path with Java configuration - antMatchers

Tags: spring, oauth, spring-security

Base on [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29014094/spring-oauth-resource-server-with-authorization-server-backend/29020621#29020621), I'm trying to secure everything but the login page in my spring app.

So I'm using this Java configuration files for OAuth2

The `extends` for the `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter`:

```
@Override
public void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .requestMatchers()
        .antMatchers("/**")
    .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .antMatchers("/login")
        .permitAll()
```

The `extends` for `OAuth2SsoConfigurerAdapter` {

```
 @Override
 public void match(RequestMatchers matchers) {
     matchers.antMatchers("/login");
 }

 @Override
 public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     http
        .authorizeRequests()                    
        .anyRequest()       
        .authenticated()
}
```

So, what I looking for is to have a `http 401` for every request but for `/login`.

If a login request is perform the `@EnableOAuth2Sso` annotation would be used to redirect it to the OAuth2 server.

**Update 1**

After changing the order of the filter `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter`, the /login request is not found.

```
  http
  .requestMatchers()
    .antMatchers("/**")
    .and()
.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/login")
    .permitAll()
    .anyRequest()
    .authenticated()
```

This request would be Unauthorized because any token is provided

- `~/`         http 401 Unauthorized (good)
- `~/resource`  http 401  Unauthorized (good)

But the login page is not found:

`~/login`    http 404 Not Found (bad)

The correct functionality should be a http 302 redirection to the OAuth2 server when the `~/login` is hit.

Comment: Switch the order. The order in which you specify matchers is also the order they are consulted in. The first match wins, in your case that is `anyRequest()` the `/login` one is never going to be consulted.

Comment: thanks @M. Deinum it makes sense. I think that was one of the problems, but now the `/login` page is not found. It's like the `OAuth2SsoConfigurerAdapter` configuration were overridden,