# Angular/Node and backend Spring OAuth2 – How to obtain the token from the UI?

Tags: angularjs, spring, rest, oauth, spring-security

This is my actual OAuth2 architecture:

[image]

I used [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29014094/spring-oauth-resource-server-with-authorization-server-backend/29020621#29020621) to build it.

Lets call the servers:

- **RS**: Resource Server
- **AS**: Authorization Server

The resource server has the protected `/resource`, after manually [obtaining a token from the Authorization Server](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/#_testing_the_authorization_server) I can access the protected resource:

```
$ curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" http://RS/resource
$ Hi from  resource server db9096ea-698e-4fc2-a0f9-4af6ab65ca30
```

So far so good, the data from the protected `RS/resource` is obtained.

Now, in my Angular/Node app when I press the login button a `http://RS/login` request will be fired, this is the flow:

1. `http://RS/login` : http 302, redirection to the AS.
2. `http://AS/uaa/oauth/authorize?client_id=acme&redirect_uri=http://RS/login&response_type=code&state=nTFE9R` : The user log in and the code is obtain, a http 302 is fired.
3. `http://RS/login?code=7kQJ2G&state=nTFE9R` : Http 302, is returned to the RS.
4. `http://RS/` : Is redirected to the root of the RS, but with an http 401 Unauthorized.

If you see, I never obtained access to the `http://RS/resource` from the Angular/Node app. In fact my address change to `http://RS/` in my browser.

Do you know how can I obtain access to the protected resource from my Angular Node App?